# Prove: the union of all n-tuples is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove: $\mathbb N^*=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} \mathbb N^n$ is countable.

My idea is to show this for $\mathbb N^2$ first, which is not difficult. After this I say, that every tuple, could be reduced to a 2-tuple:
$(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4) \mapsto ((n_1,n_2),n_3,n_4)$, 
$((n_1,n_2),n_3,n_4) \mapsto (((n_1,n_2),n_3),n_4)$ and so on.

Can I do this? If yes, is it formally correct? If not, does someone has hints?

Comment: I solved this exercise once with induction. $n=1$ is clear. In the induction step you need to know or show that $ N^{n+1}=N \times N^n $ i.e. show the cartesian product of countable sets is countable

Comment: @JohnDoe Induction only shows that for any finite $n$, the set $\mathbb{N}^n$ is countable. You need a more sophisticated argument to then show that their infinite union is still countable.

Comment: it is well known that union of countable sets are countable

Comment: It is well known that the *countable* union of countable sets is countable, but if the OP had that theorem at hand, then this would be a trivial problem. If this question is being asked in an intro set theory course, then this problem is being asked before knowing that theorem.

Comment: maybe he knows this theorem but has to prove the cartesian product of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: Actually this question was asked in the lecture Theoretical Computer Science. I didn't know, that countable union of countable sets is countable. But I think it is assumed to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to at some point give a function which does what you want it to. In particular, you need to show there is a bijection from the entire union of all of the $\mathbb{N}^n$ to $\mathbb{N}$, not just from each one in particular. Your idea might be able to be fleshed out to give you something that works, but in my opinion there's a simpler way using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

I'll assume $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. If you really need to include it then it's not too difficult to modify the following argument.

Let $f_n \colon \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ be given by $f_n((m_1,\ldots, m_n)) = p_1^{m_1} p_2^{m_2}\cdots p_n^{m_n}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

Let $f \colon \mathbb{N}^\ast \to \mathbb{N}$ be given by $f(x) = f_n(x)$ for the appropriate $n$ for which $x \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

Can you see why this is an injection?

Comment: Another way is to define an order $<^*$ on $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ by (i) if $m+n<m'+n$' then $(m,n)<^*(m',n')$,....(ii) if $m+n=m'+n'$ then $(m,n)<^*(m',n')$  iff $m<m'.$  The  $<^*$  sequence in ascending order is $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(2,2),$ $(3,1),(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1),(1,5),$...etc.

Comment: $f(m,n) =2^{m-1} * (2n-1)$ is the most elegant one I know.

Comment: This only works for $\mathbb{N}^2$ (or can be extended fairly easily to $\mathbb{N}^n$), but the OP needs it for the union of all of these....

Comment: Yes was more of a response to Daniel's above. Your's is effectively an extension of that to $\mathbb{n}^n$. Your's uses the theorem that says it suffices to show only an injection or( surjection in the reverse direction) instead of a bijection. The countable union theorem is a pretty immediate consequence of that. I would imagine that he either would have covered both of them or none of them. But again this is all speculative.

Comment: If you play around, you can easily make this an explicit bijection. The inverse is maybe even easier to describe: $n$ is decomposed into its prime factors and then mapped to $\mathbb{N}^{k_n}$ where $k_n$ is such that $p_{k_n}$ is the largest prime factors of $n$, mapping precisely to the number of each prime factor that appears in the factorisation of $n$, e.g. $168 = 2^3.3^1.5^0.7^1 \mapsto (3,1,0,1)$. You have to be a little careful about how you map $1$ of course, but that's some standard Hilbert Hotel stuff.

Comment: @DanRust I understand why $f_n(x)$ is an injection. But I do not understand the last step: Why is $f(x) = f_n(x)$ and f(x) injective?

Comment: Because $f_n$ and $f_m$ have disjoint images for all $n \neq m$, as the image of $f_n$ is all natural numbers with precisely $n$ distinct prime factors, and $f_m$ is all natural numbers with precisely $m$ distinct prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. The countable union of countable sets is countable, so all you have to show is $\mathbb{N}^n$ is countable for each n. I would do this inductively using the fact that if A and B are countable then $A \space \times B$ is countable. There are contexts in which $\mathbb{N}^n$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cdots \times \mathbb{N}$ are not the same thing, but for naïve set theory they are.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, to prove by by induction on $n\in \Bbb N$ that $\Bbb N^n$ is countable for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

The case $n=1$ is trivial.

Prove the case $n=2.$ Let $F_2:\Bbb N^2\to \Bbb N$ be a bijection.

There is a bijection $G_n: \Bbb N^{n+1} \to \Bbb N^n\times \Bbb N.$ So if there is a bijection $F_n:\Bbb N^n\to \Bbb N,$ then for $x\in \Bbb N^{n+1},$ let $G_n(x)=(g_n(x),h_n(x)),$ with $g_n(x)\in \Bbb N^n$ and $h_n(x)\in \Bbb N$, and let $$F_{n+1}(x)= F_2(\;(F_n(g_n(x)), h_n(x)\;). $$